# MySQL SQL: SELECT (SELECT... as variable) FROM

Tags: mysql, select

I have a simple question but I can't find an answer (please give me a link if that question is on stackoverflow forum).
Table has **orderid** and **quantity** columns.
How to select orderid, quantity, total_in_order, where total_in_order is a sum of quantity for current orderid
So the table looks the same, but with additional column.
Example:

```
orderid - quantity - **total_in_order**
 1      -  43      - **78**
 1      -  24      - **78**
 1      -  11      - **78**
 2      -  31      - **31**
 3      -   9      - **25**
 3      -  16      - **25**
```

So, how to modify `SELECT orderid, quantity, SUM(quantity) from orders;` ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join to a subselect. In the subselect calculate the totals for each orderid.

```
SELECT
    orders.orderid,
    orders.quantity,
    totals.total_in_order
FROM orders
JOIN
(
    SELECT orderid, SUM(quantity) AS total_in_order
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY orderid
) AS totals
ON orders.orderid = totals.orderid
```

Comment: Looks like I gave the exact same answer you did. Sorry I didn't see yours before I posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

First approach:

```
SELECT 
   O.orderid, 
   O.quantity, 
   ( select sum( O2.quantity) 
     from orders O2
     where O.orderid = O2.orderid ) as qty
from 
   orders O
```

Comment: I believe this would make a sub select for each row in orders, you should check out @Marks answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do it using a subquery. It should do the job.

```
SELECT A.orderid
   A.quantity
   B.sum
FROM 
   orders A JOIN ( SELECT orderid, sum(quantity) as sum from orders group by orderid) as B on(A.orderid=B.orderid)
```